# How to create a unique identifier ID across columns?

Tags: r, numeric, recode

I'm trying to prep data to be used in for various network visualisation applications in R and also Gephi.  These formats want numeric identifiers that link between two databases.  I have figured out the latter part, but I'm not able to find a succinct way to create a numeric ID variable across columns in a dataframe.  Here's some replicable code that illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
org.data <- data.frame(source=c('bob','sue','ann','john','sinbad'),
       target=c('sinbad','turtledove','Aerosmith','bob','john'))

desired.data <- data.frame(source=c('1','2','3','4','5'),
                       target=c('5','6','7','1','4'))


org.data

  source     target
1    bob     sinbad
2    sue     turtledove
3    ann     Aerosmith
4    john    bob
5    sinbad  john

desired.data

  source target
1    1      5
2    2      6
3    3      7
4    4      1
5    5      4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a base R method using `match` on the unlisted unique names in the original data.frame.

To replace the current data.frame, use

```
org.data[] <- sapply(org.data, match, table=unique(unlist(org.data)))
```

Here, `sapply` loops through the variables in org.data, and applies `match` to each. `match` returns the position of of the first argument in the table argument. Here, table is the unlisted unique elements in org.data: `unique(unlist(org.data))`. In this case, `sapply` returns a matrix. It is converted to a data.frame, replacing the original by appending `[]` to org.data in `org.data[] <-`. This construction can be thought of as preserving the structure of the original object during the assignment.

To construct a new data.frame, use

```
setNames(data.frame(sapply(org.data, match, table=unique(unlist(org.data)))),
         names(org.data))
```

Or better, as Henrik suggests, it would probably be easier to first create a copy of the data.frame and then use the first line of code to fill in the copy rather than using `setNames` and `data.frame`.

```
desired.data <- org.data
```

Both of these return

```
  source target
1      1      5
2      2      6
3      3      7
4      4      1
5      5      4
```

Comment: Even if OP wants to construct a new dataframe, you may create a copy of the original, and then assign the result of your first code to the copy. `desired.data <- org.data`; `desired.data[] <- sapply(org.data, match, table=unique(unlist(org.data)))` (to save you from `setNames(data.frame(`, because we have to assume the result will be assigned sooner or later anyway?) . +1!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Henrik. It would probably simpler to first create a copy and may result in fewer intermediary copies.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind explaining, briefly, what is happening here?

Comment: @elliot I've added some additional commentary.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
org.data[] <- as.numeric(factor(c(as.matrix(org.data)), levels = unique(c(as.matrix(org.data)))))
org.data
  source target
1      1      5
2      2      6
3      3      7
4      4      1
5      5      4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following. The idea is to create factors using levels over all unique names.

```
library(tidyverse)
org.data %>% 
  mutate(source2 = factor(source, levels=unique(unlist(org.data)) ,  labels=1:length(unique(unlist(org.data))))) %>% 
  mutate(target2 = factor(target, levels=unique(unlist(org.data)) ,  labels=1:length(unique(unlist(org.data)))))
  source     target source2 target2
1    bob     sinbad       1       5
2    sue turtledove       2       6
3    ann  Aerosmith       3       7
4   john        bob       4       1
5 sinbad       john       5       4
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to factors, then to integers.

```
org.data <- data.frame(source=c('bob','sue','ann','john','sinbad'),
                       target=c('sinbad','turtledove','Aerosmith','bob','john'))

# need to make sure that columns are characters, not factors
org.data$source <- as.character(org.data$source)
org.data$target <- as.character(org.data$target)

# define possible values that cover the two columns
levels <- unique(c(org.data$source, org.data$target))

# factorize, then cast to integer
org.data$source <- as.integer(factor(org.data$source, levels=levels))
org.data$target <- as.integer(factor(org.data$target, levels=levels))

org.data
```